# Why not "mv -r" in Linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Well, I know you have to use -r with cp and rm when dealing with directories. It makes this job recursively (meaning it coping and removing all starting with things inside).
But why you dont do "mv -r" when moving / renaming directories?

Comment: Fundamentals: [xfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) organizes its directory contents in a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directories are just collections of pointers to locations of files on the filesystem. When you move a directory you are updating the file pointers of the new and old parents to contain/remove the one you moved. Thus, child file pointers inside do not require recursive action as none of the pointer locations have actually changed for them.

EDIT: I've just found a much more detailed answer on Unix & Linux StackExchange that will help explain this further.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46066/why-unix-mv-program-doesnt-need-r-recursive-option-for-directories-but-cp-do

Answer (score 0):

For every move, new location is needed.
If one wants to move all files under directory alongwith the directory, just move the directory which  is recursive.

Comment: In other words, renaming a directory just requires updating that one entry. You don't have to do anything to each file inside it.